# Windows Forms window changes its size when I create a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, resize, interop

I have a `System.Window.Forms.Form` where I handle every button click. When I receive the first event I create a new WPF `System.Windows.Window` object.

```
class WPF_Window : Window
{
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WPF_Window wnd = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (wnd == null)
        {
            wnd = new WPF_Window();
        }
    }
}
```

On my computer this code works as expected, but if I run it on another computer (both Windows 10) when I click the Windows Forms window changes its size (decreasing its dimensions).

How is it possible? How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: is both computer have same DPI ?

Comment: It's got something to do with DPI. When you first use assembly from WPF, Windows Forms applications are getting resized randomly. My guess is you need to declare application as not DPI aware in manifest.

Comment: @AnkurTripathi actually these computes have different DPI, setting both to 100% makes the application works. But how can I do to avoid this behavior without changing the DPI?

Comment: @ghord The applicazion is a WinForms application, where have I to set that it is not DPI aware exaclty? How?

Comment: You have to set every width and height as per DPI wait i write some code and give it to you..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You discovered that WPF calls SetProcessDPIAware().  It happens inside the module initializer for PresentationCore.  Which is formally illegal, it must always be called before an app creates any windows or load DLLs that might cache the DPI value.  Or in other words, lots of ways that this can go wrong, you only discovered the mild version of it as yet.  Not normally a problem in a pure WPF app since PresentationCore always needs to be loaded before any window can be created.

They did leave a back-door to disable this behavior.  Copy/paste this code, best in the AssemblyInfo.cs source file for your EXE project:

```
   [assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]
```

But that isn't much of a true fix of course, DPI virtualization is now always enabled for all of your windows.  Get ahead by declaring your app dpi-aware in its manifest so that PresentationCore can't mess this up.  But with the inevitable side-effect that you'll now discover that you need to fix your Winforms UI.  It can only get smaller when you changed the Form.AutoScaleMode property or do something unwise like hard-coding the window size.  The attribute is the Q&D fix.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in other replies that is because of the *DPI awareness*. A quick fix to turn it off for those using VB.NET:

Open the *app.manifest*

[image]

And then uncomment this part and set the DPI awareness to *false*:

[image]

Note that this might cause your application's fonts to look more blurry on higher DPI devices.

Answer (score 2):

These is some method you can use. Set the width and height of the window:

```
public static Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
public static double GetDIPIndependent(double value, double DPI)
{
    value = value * (graphics.DpiX / DPI);
    return value;
}
public static double GetDIPDependent(double value, double DPI)
{
    value = value * (DPI / graphics.DpiX);
    return value;
}
public static double GetDIPIndependent(double value)
{
    value = value * (graphics.DpiX / 96.0);
    return value;
}

public static double GetDIPDependent(double value)
{
    value = value * (96.0 / graphics.DpiX);
    return value;
}
```

### Example:

#### If DPI independent

```
this.Width = GetDIPIndependent(this.Width)
this.Height = GetDIPIndependent(this.Height)
```

#### If DPI dependent

```
this.Width = GetDIPDependent(this.Width)
this.Height = GetDIPDependent(this.Height)
```

It works for me...

Comment: The width and height are the Form properties? and when should I set them? Once on startup?

Comment: yes width and height are the Form properties..,,,,  and can change tham at Loaded method of the window                                                                     this.Loaded += Window_Loaded();

Comment: It doesn't work for me, neither by using GetDIPIndependent nor GetDIPDependent... The window on the computer with DPI set to 150% still resizes itself.

Comment: if computer is 100% and you want to set width 800 than its looks like 800 ... but if computer is 150% you want to set width 800 than its looks like 512 (DIPDependent)   show me your code where you set width and height and possible to show images whats happen ..

Comment: I set width and height after InitializeComponent() (the code is the same of my question)

Comment: first use loaded method and set width and height in the loaded method .. and what happen exactly ...