# Windows Forms resized after loading WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, resize, windows-10, dpi

I'm experiencing a strange behavior, one for which I currently do not have an explanation or a solution and I'm hoping someone knows something about this.

So I have a simple Windows Forms application with a single button, which on button click will load a `PresentationFramework` assembly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Assembly.Load("PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
    }
}
```

Now when I have a custom scaling size (for instance 200%) set on my Windows 10 then on a button click the Form will get resized, see the following images.

**- BEFORE CLICK:**

[image: Form1 before button click]

**- AFTER CLICK:**

[image: Form1 after button click]

However this behavior does not occur when I'm using any of the provided scaling options (when I'm not using custom scaling):

[image: Scaling options]

I initially thought the problem is related to `Form.AutoScaleMode`, but it doesn't seem to be. Also I'm unable to observe any changed value in `Form` object.

Comment: This questions has also been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242963/windows-forms-window-changes-its-size-when-i-create-a-wpf-window).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that I completely understand your issue here but you could try to add the following attribute to your `AssemblyInfo`.cs file (you'll find it under the Properties node in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio):

```
[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]
```

This will allow the application to disable to use dots per inch (dpi) awareness for all user interface elements.

Comment: That worked, many thanks! Unfortunately I still don't understand why issue occurred in the first place, why does the change occur after the PresentationFramework is loaded?

Comment: my guess is that WPF's DpiAwareness somehow breaks WinForms one when they are used in single application.